# Routing to Different component in react

Tags: reactjs, typescript, routes

I have App Component , InputComponent and Display Component.

By Default I will load Input Component and it has one input text box and submit button. Onclicking that Submit button in Input Component , i want to Navigate to Display Component with the name entered in the input field.

[App.js](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Iwjkf.png)

[Input Component.js](https://i.stack.imgur.com/U6QAp.png)[DisplayComponent.js](https://i.stack.imgur.com/w996E.png)

Source code is attached as images.
Pls guide me a proper solution.. Any help much appreciated.

Comment: Can you please post your code as text instead of image? At least the related part for your question of the component. Thanks!

Comment: try to move your display route( <Route path='/display' ..... </Route>) to App.js file.

Answer (score 0):

In App.js:
this should be the code if you want "Input Component" to display by default

```
<BrowserRouter>
    <Switch>
      <Route exact path="/" component={InputComponent}/>
      </Switch>
</BrowserRouter>
```

You need to use any kind of state management(CONTEXT API or REDUX) for storing your data, in order to display your data in other component. or you can just pass the data as props to other components